# Activate checkboxes in Userform frame if caption matches comma delimited values in textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi-userform where the user makes multiple selections (comboboxes, listboxes & checkboxes) and it gets saved in a spreadsheet, they have the ablibity to edit what they have saved from dictonaries that I've created.

The problem I am facing are that I can't figure out how to activate the checkboxes they previously selected, it's like 40 checkboxes in a frame and the caption of the checkbox are saved as a comma-delimited text (see code below).

Current workaround are that I today show which checkboxes they previously selected in an textbox, would it be easier to lookup if any value in the textbox matches the checkboxes in the frame?

```
Dim chk As Control
Dim pm As String, delimiter As String
For Each chk In Me.PlanningMarkets2.Controls
    If TypeOf chk Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        If (chk.Value) Then
            pm = pm & delimiter & chk.Caption
            delimiter = ", "
        End If
    End If
Next
With pmSheet
    Cells(lastrow, 7).Value = pm
End With
```

When the user goes to the Edit part of the userform searching for their previous saved input will the checkboxes that ealier was selected be activated.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve. There are different tabs, one where you click checkboxes, and one where you reflect the choices made somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example along the lines of what you need. Based on a userform with checkboxes that looks like this:

[image]

Look at the code behind the userform below. You'll see that the `SaveButton_Click` method creates a comma-delimited list of checkbox captions and stores in it a temporary variable. You can store this out to your worksheet or where ever. The `RestoreButton_Click` method `Splits` the list into an array so we can quickly search for the caption in `CaptionInList`.

Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit

Private savedChecks As String

Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            '--- all checkboxes are cleared
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub RestoreButton_Click()
    Dim captions() As String
    captions = Split(savedChecks, ",")

    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If CaptionInList(captions, ctl.caption) Then
                ctl.Value = True
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
    savedChecks = vbNullString
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If ctl.Value = True Then
                '--- only save the checkboxes that are checked
                savedChecks = savedChecks & ctl.caption & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Function CaptionInList(ByRef captionList As Variant, ByVal caption As String) As Boolean
    Dim cap As Variant
    For Each cap In captionList
        If cap = caption Then
            CaptionInList = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cap
End Function
```